# User already exists error in PHP

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP and working with PDO and MySQL. I am going to filter user input data using this code:

```
if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'$username')||!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'$password'))
        {
            echo "username or password already exists....";
        }

        else
        {
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Username,Password) VALUES (:username,:password)";
$q=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':username'=>$username,':password'=>$password));
$count=$q->rowCount();
echo "inserted $count rows.\n";
```

But it shows an error, which is simply show the message:

```
username or password already exists
```

If the username or password does not exist it show the same message? If `filter_input()` should not be used here then what can I use instead?

Comment: We have to know what `filter_input` and `INPUT_POST` does

Comment: http://www.php.net/filter_input

Comment: As per your conversation with @Kolink, the keyword `filter_input` only does basic input filtering, and does not talk to your database at all. You will need to do a query to determine whether a username exists or not (`SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username`).

Comment: Incidentally, you should be salting and hashing your password storage. In general, you should use a library rather than writing your own authentication system - it is very hard to get right.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,'$username')
```

is wrong, it expects the array key name - without any preceding dollar (if you don't name the get variable with a dollar):

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,'username')
```

should be correct. Remove the `$` sign also for your password filter.

---

First line would be then:

```
if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'username')||!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'password'))
```

Comment: plz add your code to my code

Answer (score 0):

The name given to `filter_input` should not contain a `$`, unless of course the form actually has `<input name="$username" />`.

Comment: In which case you must use $$ to escape the $, if i remember well.

Comment: No need to escape it since it is in single quotes. `$$` is for variable variables.

Comment: Then no need to say that the name should not contain a $.

Comment: plz clear it i can't understand

Comment: Just remove the `$` from `'$username'` and `'$password'`. Or just do it the normal way and test `if( empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))`

Comment: DEAR! i don't want to check the EMPTY() string for username and password, i just want that when a user input a string like username and the same username is already exists in my data base then it check for it and show a message that the username is valid or not.

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with `filter_input()`...

Comment: if you have any idea plz add it to my code